# Fastest way to compute the solution of this equation

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I am looking for the solutions to the equation :
$$a_1+...+a_n =x$$
with
$$ -3 \leq a_i\in \mathbb {Z} \leq 3 \ \ \ \ \ \forall i$$
$$x \in \mathbb Z$$

Mathematica will get you the solutions eventually with ( x == tot, and varNbr==n) :

`Solutions[tot_, varNbr_] :=  Block[{ unknowns= Symbol["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[varNbr] }, Solve[Total[unknowns] == tot&& ( -4 < # < 4) & /@ unknowns, unknowns, Integers] ]`

but it's very slow for big  variable numbers. (try it with varNbr around 10 for example, not 1000).

Do you have faster solutions ?

Comment: In view of [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135240/bounded-partitions-and-bounded-signed-partitions-of-integers) nothing simple is expected.

Comment: Require the variables to be ordered to eliminate permutations of the same values. `Solutions[tot_Integer, varNbr_Integer?Positive] := 
 Module[{unknowns = Array[a, varNbr]}, 
  Solve[Total[unknowns] == tot && (LessEqual @@ unknowns) && 
    And @@ ((-4 < # < 4) & /@ unknowns), unknowns, Integers]]`

Comment: `FrobeniusSolve` solves the same equation with different bounds -- maybe it could be adapted or not.  Probably it's easiest to loop through $a_n =x -(a_1+...+a_{n-1})$ and select the ones for which $3\le a_n\le3$.

Comment: @BobHanlon: These are different solutions which form the same partition. The OP asks for solutions.

Comment: @MichaelE2: First, `FrobeniusSolve` finds only non-negative integer solutions. Second, `FrobeniusSolve[{1,1,1,1,1},123]` killed my comp so I have to restart it.

Comment: @user64494 "FrobeniusSolve finds only non-negative integer solutions" -- so I said...again, you're focused on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's precisely what [`IntegerPartitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) does. For example, for $n=10$ and $x=12$ we have 157 ordered solutions,

```
IntegerPartitions[12, {10}, Range[-3, 3]]
(*    {{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, -3, -3, -3},
       {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, -2, -3, -3},
       {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, -1, -3, -3},
       ...
       {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}    *)
```

If you want all permutations of these (all unordered solutions), apply [`Permutations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) to each ordered solution. There are now $3\,039\,400$ solutions,

```
Join @@ Permutations /@ %
(*    {{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, -3, -3, -3},
       {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, -3, 3, -3, -3},
       {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, -3, -3, 3, -3},
       ...
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}    *)
```

All together in one function:

```
solutions[x_, n_] := 
  Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[x, {n}, Range[-3, 3]]
```