# Is there a better way : solutions to integer equation

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, memory, computational-complexity

I have the following code which solves for Integers the equation
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4+c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=tot$$
with
$$ -4<a_i\in \mathbb{Z}<4$$
$$ -7<b_i\in \mathbb{Z}<7$$
$$ -4<c_i\in \mathbb{Z}<4$$
**Notice that the constraint on b is different**

My method for the moment is the following :

*1-* find the solutions to
$$a+b+c=tot$$
with
$$ -13<a=\sum a_i<13$$
$$ -25<b=\sum b_i<25$$
$$ -13<c=\sum c_i<13$$
I use this code to do it (*forget about the nbLd argument, it's zero for all you care*), it gives a `List` of solutions.

```
Solutions[tot_, nbLd_: 0(*forget about nbLd, it's zero*)] := Block[{},
   Values@
    Solve[a + b + c == tot && -13 < a < 13 && -25 + 6*nbLd < b < 
       25 - 6*nbLd && -13 < c < 13 , {a, b, c}, Integers]];
```

2- I use these solutions to  find the $\{a_i\},\{b_i\},\{c_i\}$ using `IntegerPartitions` and `Permutations`(see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240178/fastest-way-to-compute-the-solution-of-this-equation/240195#240195))  as well as `Reap` and `Sow`
to find all the solutions to the initial equation. (There is some additional formatting done with `Flatten`). I use this code to do it:

```
GenNodes[tot_] :=
  Block[{partitions = Solutions[tot], temp},
   (Partition[Flatten[#], 2]) & /@ (*Formatting line*)
    Flatten[Table[{#[[1, j]], #[[2, i]], #[[3, k]]}, {j, 
         Length[#[[1]]]}, {i, Length[#[[2]]]}, {k, 
         Length[#[[3]]]}](*with this Table line, 
       I cobine all the different a_i,b_i,
       c_i solutions to get all possible solutions, 
       I need all permutations*)& /@ (Reap[(
            temp = {
              
              IntegerPartitions[#[[1]], {4}, 
               Range[-3, 3]],(*a_i solutions*)
              
              IntegerPartitions[#[[2]], {4}, 
               Range[-6, 6]],(*b_i solutions*)
              
              IntegerPartitions[#[[3]], {4}, 
               Range[-3, 3]]}; (*c_i solutions*)
            
            If[temp[[1]] != {} && temp[[2]] != {} && temp[[3]] != {}, 
             Sow[{Join @@ Permutations /@ temp[[1]], 
               Join @@ Permutations /@ temp[[2]], 
               Join @@ Permutations /@ temp[[3]]}], 
             Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]) & /@ partitions, e][[1]]), 3]];
```

The final result is for example :

```
In[82]:= GenNodes[47]

Out[82]= {{{3, 3}, {3, 2}, {6, 6}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 
   3}, {2, 3}, {6, 6}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 2}, {3, 3}, {6, 
   6}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 3}, {6, 6}, {6, 6}, {3, 
   3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}, {6, 6}, {6, 5}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{3,
    3}, {3, 3}, {6, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}, {6, 
   5}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}, {5, 6}, {6, 6}, {3, 
   3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}, {6, 6}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 2}}, {{3,
    3}, {3, 3}, {6, 6}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}, {6, 
   6}, {6, 6}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}, {6, 6}, {6, 6}, {2, 
   3}, {3, 3}}}
```

Which, hopefully, are all the solutions to the initial equation for $tot=47$, formatted in a certain way.

**My goal is to find the solutions of this equation for $tot =32$**, as it is right now, my computer cannot do it. It freezes (I don't really know why, I'm not an expert, I don't understand why it can't just do it slowly, it maybe a memory problem ? but it freezes super fast, so I don't think it is. It would be helpful if someone could explain this to me !).

**Question:** *basically, can you do it ?*

**Alternative question:** *Do yo have a better (memory usage wise or speed wise) way to find the solutions ? or to improve **any** of the steps?*

**I'll take any advice**

Note: Beware, for 32 the number of solutions is **huge**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `Solve` straight?

```
f[tot_Integer] := 
  Solve[a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 == tot
        && -4 < a1 <= a2 <= a3 <= a4 < 4
        && -7 < b1 <= b2 <= b3 <= b4 < 7
        && -4 < c1 <= c2 <= c3 <= c4 < 4,
        {a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4}, Integers]
```

In this way, only ordered solutions are found and you can permute them at will afterwards.

Example:

```
f[47]
(*    {{a1 -> 2, a2 -> 3, a3 -> 3, a4 -> 3, b1 -> 6, b2 -> 6, b3 -> 6, b4 -> 6, c1 -> 3, c2 -> 3, c3 -> 3, c4 -> 3},
       {a1 -> 3, a2 -> 3, a3 -> 3, a4 -> 3, b1 -> 5, b2 -> 6, b3 -> 6, b4 -> 6, c1 -> 3, c2 -> 3, c3 -> 3, c4 -> 3},
       {a1 -> 3, a2 -> 3, a3 -> 3, a4 -> 3, b1 -> 6, b2 -> 6, b3 -> 6, b4 -> 6, c1 -> 2, c2 -> 3, c3 -> 3, c4 -> 3}}    *)
```

The case you're interested in:

```
F32 = f[32];
F32 // Length
(*    23978    *)
```

So there are only 23978 ordered solutions.

To construct **all** unordered solutions, permute:

```
F = {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}} /. F32;
G = Flatten[Tuples[Permutations /@ #] & /@ F, 1];
Length[G]
(*    11694943    *)
```

So there are about 11 million solutions:

```
G
(*    {{{-3, -3, -1, 3}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {3, 3, 3, 3}},
       {{-3, -3, 3, -1}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {3, 3, 3, 3}},
       {{-3, -1, -3, 3}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {3, 3, 3, 3}},
       ...
       {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {0, -1, -2, -1}},
       {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {0, -1, -1, -2}},
       {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {-1, -1, -1, -1}}}    *)
```

Comment: Cause sometimes I'm dumb

Comment: I Just want to delete my question, it's kind of embarrassing

Comment: No need to delete. Niels Bohr said: An expert is a man who has made all the mistakes which can be made, in a narrow field.